# Override serilog minimumlevel for specific sink using appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog, asp.net-core-2.1

There is documentation for "globally" overriding MinimumLevel in code, xml and [json](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#level-overrides).

But can I override for a specific sink, using `appsettings.json`? For example, I want to log at warning level for class `MyClass`, but only for the console sink.

Comment: Your first stop for such questions should be the [ASP.NET Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configuration) and [Filter Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#create-filter-rules-in-configuration) as its well documented on how to set per class/namespace logging level

Comment: @Tseng Those examples are for the built in logging. I'm using Serilog.

Comment: As long you plug it in with the `ILoggerFactory` and use `ILogger<T>` in your classes, it will be applied to it too. See https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore. `ILoggerFactory` and `ILogger<T>` are abstractions and the logging config works for all of that one which implement/are based on these abstractions

Answer (score 10):

Just use the **restrictedToMinimumLevel** param in the config section of the specific sink:

```json
{
  /* .. */
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose", /* <-- set the default level to the LOWEST applicable for your app  */
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.SystemConsoleTheme::Literate, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information" /* <-- set the minimum level for specific sink  */
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          /* .. */
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning" /* <-- set the minimum level for specific sink  */
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Udp",
        "Args": {
          /* .. */
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Warning" /* <-- set the minimum level for specific sink  */
        }
      }
    ],
    /* .. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you have custom Override per sink?

Answer (score 1):

I am interested in this question too. I can't find a solution. Apparently this cannot be done on correct.It can turn out like this:

1. Create two sections of SERILOG (Serilog and Serilog2 or SerilogLow)
2. configure the minimum logging level for each partition individually
3. to register for both sections.

List item

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.ConfigurationSection(_configuration.GetSection("Serilog"))
    .ReadFrom.ConfigurationSection(_configuration.GetSection("SerilogLow")).CreateLogger();
    services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(logger);
}
```

HTH